# TouchableOpacity fails on second render with React Native Testing Library

Tags: react-native, jestjs, integration-testing, react-native-testing-library

When I test component containing `TouchableOpacity` with `React-Native` testing library, first time render is ok, second time in test suite test always fails.

If I replace `TouchableOpacity` with `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, render will go ok. Other animated `Touchable's` fail too.

**The tested component**

```js
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const TestedComponent = () => (
  <TouchableOpacity testID="tested-component">
    <Text>Button</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

**The tests (two are identical)**

```js
describe('TestedComponent', () => {
  test('should render TestedComponent', () => {
    render(<TestedComponent />);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('tested-component')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('should render TestedComponent', () => {
    render(<TestedComponent />);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('tested-component')).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

First one passes second fails. When I change their order — the same happens

**Error I get**

```js
console.error
      Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
      1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
      2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
      3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
      See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      16 |
      17 |   test('should render TestedComponent', () => {
    > 18 |     render(<TestedComponent />, {
         |           ^
      19 |       createNodeMock: () => {},
      20 |     });
      21 |
```

**And one more**

```js
The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:
      
          at /Users/tetyana/Documents/UWRead/Codebase/uwr-mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/createAnimatedComponent.js:36:57
          at TouchableOpacity (/Users/tetyana/Documents/UWRead/Codebase/uwr-mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js:132:23)
          at TouchableOpacity
          at TestedComponent
      
      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      16 |
      17 |   test('should render TestedComponent', () => {
    > 18 |     render(<TestedComponent />, {
         |           ^
      19 |       createNodeMock: () => {},
      20 |     });
      21 |
```

**And one more**

```js
● TestedComponent › should render TestedComponent

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')

      16 |
      17 |   test('should render TestedComponent', () => {
    > 18 |     render(<TestedComponent />, {
         |           ^
      19 |       createNodeMock: () => {},
      20 |     });
      21 |
```

I tried different components, as well as browsing `React`, `React-Native` and testing library docs, do different types of cleanups but with no result.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong, but the docs tell you go better with ```Pressable```(https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.
I had setupTests.js running where was a block

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});
```

It caused the failure.